# Is it possible to link a calendar to a list column within a custom list?

Tags: calendar

I have a created an employee roster for a specific project using a custom list. However, i would like to include a column in this list that links up to a calendar which shows the employee's schedule. After searching on google, i was not able to find a single excample of a calendar list that has been linked to a list column within a custom list, either as a lookup column or even as a link.

The ideal scenario would be a lookup column in the custom list that pulls up the employee's calendar.

Or

A link in the list column (e.g like in the case of a Title column which is linked to an edit menu that opens as a modal)that when clicked on, opens up the emoployee's calendar - preferably as a modal dialog.

Is this possible - code or no code?

Thanks - Pat

Comment: By 'Calendar', are you referring to a Calendar in SharePoint or the user's calendar in Outlook/Exchange?

Comment: Hi Dave, By Calendar, i mean a Sharepoint Calendar, not an outlook or any other calendar.